# Sharing PDF with comments from IPad

Tags: ipad, adobe

I have a PDF file in my IPad and I want to send it to a colleague. Unfortunately, when I tried to send it he does not receive the comments, even if I put (Share flattened copy)

How can I do it? What are the common problems that I might be having?

Comment: Not an expert at all but I've looked into this in the past and found it to be a nightmare. A lot of different PDF readers store annotations and comments in their own format and rarely have embedded options for sharing those. The annotations thus do not become part of the actual PDF, but are usually stored separately. So the best way would be a google search on the specific app you are using and start searching from there. Or get a reader that has a specific and embedded option for sharing comments/annotations and to make sure that you and your colleague are using the same app.

Comment: What application are you using to annotate the PDF and what application/platorm (PC/iOS/Mac etc) is your colleague using?

Answer (score 1):

I don't work for the company or anything but this company/platform seem to be becoming a standard for this kind of thing

https://pdfexpert.com

In the Apple universe you could try and open the document in Pages, modify it, then share your changes online with the latest iCloud/iWork sharing features.